# Regex : extract a particular data

Tags: regex

I have a line say

word: 'sometext'

I need a regex which displays only sometext without the quotes.

I am using something like this `(?m)(word:)(.*){1}` but I am not able to extract the data

Comment: do specify the language you are using

Comment: There is nothing in your regex that tests for quotes, so why do you use it? Did you not try anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are matching any character zero or more times right after `word:` which will also select the single quote. You can omit `{1}`

You could use a capturing group inside the single quotes and using a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) you can match not a quote. Your value will be in the capturing group.

[`word: '([^']+)'`](https://regex101.com/r/cHfdmK/1)